# Why parameter type is needed for expanded function when there are more than 1 parameter?

Tags: scala

I have a function:

```
def adder(a: Int, b: Int) = a+b
```

and when I try to get the curried function:

```
val addOne = adder(1, _)     //error: missing parameter type for expanded function
val addOne = adder(1, _:Int) //Works
```

I thought it could be due to distinction for different parameter types with the same name. But then it works for functions with only one parameter:

```
def square(a: Int) = a*a
val squareFunc = square(_)
```

No error. Why is the restrictions on only parameter number > 1?

If the reasoning is due to parameter type distinction, we should still allow this for lambda variables. For example, this should be allowed since one variable can only hold one lambda with specific parameter type:

```
val adder: (Int,Int)=>Int = _+_
val addOne = adder(1,_)             //Still error, but should be allowed?
```

Is there any discussion or documentation somewhere that I can dive into?

Comment: Have you tried 1 variable argument??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an old limitation in the Scala compiler. This was actually just recently fixed and back-ported to Scala 2.12.8!

```
Welcome to Scala 2.12.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_152).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> def adder(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
adder: (a: Int, b: Int)Int

scala> val addOne = adder(1, _)
addOne: Int => Int = $$Lambda$3978/16149813@813a8ff
```

It was discussed [here](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/2570), and fixed [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7333).